# Migrating from Access db to SQL Server 2008 with frontend ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2007

I did the upsizing of access database to sql server. My question is, do I have to change all my  datasources in webpages manually or is there any way to do that without much effort.

Edit: The queries I have uses user input I mean `@WhichUser` and sql server throwing error for those asking me name the scalar variables. Normally `@` symbol works in sql server but not in mine. Is this because I am using an express edition or is there anything else that I need to add to the query. Thanks!

Comment: So your connection string(s) aren't in web.config?

Comment: sorry not connection string but the data control sources like gridview, detailsview, dropdownlists I have so many of them and code behind so I have to change each and everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I named Control Parameter names same as column names while I used Which infront of every input parameter like `@WhichUser` so was solved by adding `WhichUser` as name to the control parameter.